# Как сверстать элементы, которые тянутся за экран

Tags: css, css3

как верстать линию которая тянется в одну сторону за пределы контейнера до бесконечности, постоянно должна упираться в край экрана 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот как на макете, я не могу найти оптимального решения, что ещё нормально и заадаптивить, появляется горизонтальная прокрутка все время сейчас я остановился вот на этом, но этот код при адаптиве дает горизонтальную прокрутку

```css
 .row-after-title
  margin-bottom: 60px
  margin-top: 10px
  width: 400%
  height: 11px
  background-color: $accent
  margin-left: calc(50% - 590px)
  position: relative
  &::before
   position: absolute
   content: ''
   background-color: $accent
   width: 11px
   height: 52px
   left: -14px
   transform: skew(20deg);
   bottom: 0px
```

Comment: Задавайте стили элементу в который вложен контейнер

Comment: и если можно то с примером css что бы понятно было

Comment: Вы свой код добавляйте, даже если не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с псевдо-елементом.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  border-left: 15px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: 15px solid yellow;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transform: skewx(20deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: вот у меня получилось тоже самое, но я когда адаптив проверяю, то все просто уходит в сторону

Comment: Я не понимаю, что значит "все уходит", вы добавльйте скриншоты, а лучше код с проблемой. Данный блок будет уходить за пределы только при размерах меньше 600px, из за своих размеров. Но, ничто не мешает вам добавить медиа запросы и подогнать отступы.

Comment: так что не понятного на экране появляется горизонтальная прокрутка с этой линией

Comment: @dmitro_bolva, Если бы вы запустили мой пример, то увидели, что горизонтальной прокрутки нет ни на каких разрешениях. Так как для `body` заданно свойство `overflow: hidden`;

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть контейнер. В нем находится заголовок который тянется на всю ширину контейнера. Под заголовком бордер, который также тянется на всю ширину. Второй блок под заголовком список ul с элементами li. Этот список не тянется на всю ширину контейнера в котором находится. В чем, таки, сложность?

Comment: наверное в том что если вы не заметили он идёт в одну сторону а не просто через всю ширину экрана, он должен тянутся только вправо

Comment: и я же написал что красным это я выделил размеры контейнера для наглядности, то есть мне нужно тянуть за пределы контейнера до бесконечности и в одну только сторону

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, вы используете bootstrap сетку, если так, то почему вы просто не можете заключить заголовок с этой полоской в col определенного размера, что бы элемент не выходил за пределы вашего div class ="col..." Элемента?

А вообще лучше выкладывать и код сразу, потому что трудно решить проблему не имея перед глазами код..